# Early grey environment setup

Tags: earlgrey

I'm trying to get Earlgrey setup on my computer by following the steps for Cocoapod installation as described [here](https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/blob/master/docs/install-and-run.md#cocoapods-)

After performing all the steps I keep on getting compilation error during build

EarlGrey.swift:17:27: Use of undeclared type 'EarlGreyImpl'

There are 13 such compilation errors all related to unresolved identifier.

I re-tried the steps multiple times with same results. My folder structure matches with what is shown in the instructions.

Any suggestions where should i look further to get this resolved.

For reference i'm using [this](http://cdn1.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/TipCalculator-Demo4.zip)  swift project as base for writing test cases.

Answer (score 2):

So the issue was related to BridgingHeader.h file setting in

**test target -> build Setting -> Swift compiler -Code generation -> Objective-C bridging Header**

I copied the file from demo project, but did not specify it in the above setting. Once specified there, the compilation errors was gone.

Answer (score 1):

Try importing EarlGrey using `#import <EarlGrey/EarlGrey.h>` instead of `@import EarlGrey;`